# Serving Python Flask Under IIS as an Application Under Default Web Site

Tags: python, flask, iis

I have a WebServer running which has two different application under Default WebSite as portal and server. I would like to create an another application hosted by flask and python to be served. I was able to do it by creating a new website named as flask but i would like to create as an application.

I could not find any guide to serve it under Default Web Site as an application is there a way?
Below you can see i hosted as an web site as flask, it works but i need to host it under my domain to access it from internet, however i could not make correct configurations to serve it under Default Web Site as an application.

[image]

Comment: If you use HttpPlatformHandler, the same steps should apply to an application, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which method you used to deploy your Flask app, I think you should pay attention to its routing issue:`@app.route("/FlaskApp/")`. I did some simple tests like this(with FastCGI):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/FlaskApp/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from FastCGI via IIS!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[image]

```
web.config

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="flaskhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python\python.exe|C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FlaskApp" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```